(Reverse) Discretization of first order (simple) nonlinear ODE
I'm trying to understand how a paper I'm reading uses the bilateral transform to convert a discrete difference equation to an ODE. The paper is related to control theory so I tried to use bilateral transform to convert between Z-domain and s-domain (Tustin's method) of the transfer function.
However, I quickly realised this isn't possible because the equation is non-linear so I cannot find the transfer function. Since the paper includes the discrete and continuous equations I tried do convert it in reverse using the trapezoid numerical integration, however the ODE contains two functions one for input and output. And all the trapezoid examples I've learnt from only have one function so I'm bit stuck.
Can someone suggest ideally how I can convert the difference equation below to the ODE below or vice versa or both. Even just what to google or where my misunderstanding is would be very much appreciated.
Difference Equation
$$y_{n+1}=y_{n}+\alpha(x_{n+1}-c)+\beta(x_{n+1}-x_{n})$$
ODE
$$\frac{dy(t)}{dt}=\alpha \frac{x(t)-c}{T}+(\beta+\frac{\alpha}{2})\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$$
Where $T$ is the discrete update interval.
Just to be clear, the term (I think) that prevents using bilateral transform between z & s domain is the $-c$ term making it non-linear.
And I cannot use the trapezoid rule (I think) because the there are two functions, and the $y$ function is not an ODE because the derivative of $y$ is not defined in terms of $y$ (i.e. $y$ doesn't appear on the right side of the ODE).

Can you link the paper or cite the source (name, author(s), ...)?

Sure it's "PIE: A Lightweight Control Scheme to Address the Bufferbloat Problem" by Pan et al.
I tried to convert the unnecessary details in my original question. The paper has an algorithm for calculating p (drop probability) in section III B, that is the equivalent of the difference equation I mentioned above.
And in section V they convert that algorithm to an ODE which is equation 4 of that section.
Replace y and x in my above examples to p and tao and they should be equivalent.

@DomeMaster Your difference equation seems to be part of a system of difference equations.

@PierreCarre Yes that is correct. That's why I tried to use the bilinear transform (Tustin's method) between z-domain and s-domain. However, I couldn't compute a z-domain transfer function because the difference equation is non-linear due to the ($-T_{ref}$ term).
Do you have any suggestions how to handle that problem? Thank-you

Or you could expand the difference equation around the midpoint, that is, inserting $$x(t+h/2)\pm x'(t+h/2)h/2+O(h^2)$$ for $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$. Then
$$
y_{n+1}-y_n=y'(t+h/2)h=α\Bigl(x(t+h/2)+x'(t+h/2)h/2−c\Bigr)+β x'(t+h/2)h +O(h^2).
$$
Combined and simplified and ignoring terms proportional to $h$ or smaller, this results in the cited equation
$$
y'=α(x-c)/h+(β+α/2)x'.
$$

I'm sort of new to this site so don't know the etiquette. I think both our solutions work but I'll give you the correct answer as a thank-you!

First and second order discretizations work mostly as intuition would tell. Going beyond that involves less intuitive coefficients or terms. In a certain sense one could say that it reverses the construction of Runge-Kutta or multi-step methods.

In my original question the $-c$ term prevents the system from being a linear mapping and instead is an affine mapping. Thus a transfer function cannot be derived and the bilinear transform indeed cannot be used.
The trick is to perturb the input x by -c before the system. So the system functions are $y$ and $(x-c)$ (instead of $y$ and $x$), making it a linear mapping thereby allowing the computation of the transfer function and enabling use of the bilinear transformation.
Worth noting a misunderstanding I had in original question. Generally, numerical methods like the trapezoid rule cannot be used in LTI systems since the input is unknown thus a recurrence relation cannot be created.
